# Unable to Delete File while starting Browser session while using maven selenium plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, maven-plugin

> **pom.xml** looks like

```
<build>    
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <background>true</background>            
                            <logOutput>true</logOutput>                             
                            <browserSessionReuse>true</browserSessionReuse>                             
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase -->
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>

            <executions>  
                  <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>  
            </executions>  
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> **JUnit TestCase**

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.co.in/");
    selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.type("q", "Selenium Sucks");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    selenium.stop();
}
```

I get this error message while executing goal '**mvn integration-test**' I have simple testcase which opens firefox browser and search for sometext in Googe search Bar.

As of now i also have reinstalled firefox browser but it again fails .

**Exception :**
    java.lang.RuntimeException: ***Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Unable to delete file C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\customProfileDirb66b3e06cba84cc1b55eb72a418a5c61\parent.lock***
        at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:89)
        at org.argus.selenium.timepass.TestSelenium.setUp(TestSelenium.java:16)

Am i missing something in configuration or while running the mvn goal.

Comment: Did you check the above mentioned temp path to see if customProfilefolders are there? Close your FF browser and then check the Temp folder

Comment: This temp folder is present and TaskManager also shows me an instance of firefox running in the background...but the issue is the firefox window doesnt pops up and test isn't played and my server exits leaving this instance alive.

Answer (score 2):

Guys Funny and Weird....
just make change to pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <background>true</background>            
                        <logOutput>true</logOutput>                             
                        <browserSessionReuse>true</browserSessionReuse>                             
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Change the version number to **1.0.1**
It should look like

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <background>true</background>            
                        <logOutput>true</logOutput>                             
                        <browserSessionReuse>true</browserSessionReuse>                             
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**This should work.**
Thanks everyone :)